# Why is the compiler-generated enumerator for "yield" not a struct?

Tags: c#, struct, heap-memory, ienumerable, yield

The [compiler-generated implementation](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx) of `IEnumerator` / `IEnumerable` for `yield` methods and getters seems to be a class, and is therefore allocated on the heap. However, other .NET types such as `List<T>` specifically return `struct` enumerators to avoid useless memory allocation. From a quick overview of the *C# In Depth* post, I see no reason why that couldn't also be the case here.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I just realized that since the return type is an interface (`IEnumerable` or `IEnumerator`), it [would get boxed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032750/) anyway, is that right? In this case, couldn't the method be changed to return an explicitly typed enumerator (like [List<T> does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0yss765(v=vs.110).aspx))? Since it implements the interfaces, all code references to it should be preserved. (IIRC, this works because `foreach` is [detected by pattern](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/06/30/following-the-pattern/)).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Servy correctly answered your question -- a question you answered yourself in a comment:

> I just realized that since the return type is an interface, it would get boxed anyway, is that right?

Right. Your follow up question is:

> couldn't the method be changed to return an explicitly typed enumerator (like `List<T>` does)?

So your idea here is that the user writes:

```
IEnumerable<int> Blah() ...
```

and the compiler actually generates a method that returns `BlahEnumerable` which is a struct that implements `IEnumerable<int>`, but with the appropriate `GetEnumerator` etc methods and properties that allow the "pattern matching" feature of `foreach` to elide the boxing.

Though that is a plausible idea, there are serious difficulties involved when you start lying about the return type of a method. **Particularly when the lie involves changing whether the method returns a struct or a reference type.**  Think of all the things that go wrong:

- Suppose the method is virtual. How can it be overridden? The return type of a virtual override method must match exactly the overridden method. (And similarly for: the method overrides another method, the method implements a method of an interface, and so on.)
- Suppose the method is made into a delegate `Func<IEnumerable<int>>`.  `Func<T>` is covariant in `T`, but covariance only applies to type arguments of reference type. The code looks like it returns an `IEnumerable<T>` but in fact it returns a value type that is not covariance-compatible with `IEnumerable<T>`, only *assignment compatible*.
- Suppose we have `void M<T>(T t) where T : class` and we call `M(Blah())`. We expect to deduce that `T` is `IEnumerable<int>`, which passes the constraint check, but the struct type does *not* pass the constraint check.

And so on.  You rapidly end up in an episode of Three's Company (boy am I dating myself here) where a small lie ends up compounding into a huge disaster.  All of this to save a small amount of collection pressure. Not worth it.

I note though that the implementation created by the compiler *does* save on collection pressure in one interesting way. The *first* time that `GetEnumerator` is called on the returned enumerable, the enumerable turns *itself* into an enumerator. The second time of course the state is different so it allocates a new object. Since the 99.99% likely scenario is that a given sequence is enumerated exactly once, this is a big savings on collection pressure.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! I'm nitpicking on collection pressure because I'm working with Unity's terrible early Mono runtime non-generational GC, so I'm looking at allocations *very* closely.

Answer (score 9):

That class will *only* ever be used through the interface.  If it were a struct, it would be boxed 100% of the time, making it *less* efficient than using a class.

You can't *not* box it, as it is, by definition, impossible to use the type at compile time as *it doesn't exist* when you start compiling the code.

When writing a custom implementation of `IEnumerator` you can expose the actual underlying type before compiling the code, allowing it to be potentially used without being boxed.