# Why isn't there an IImmutableArray<T> interface in the .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, interface, immutable-collections

In the .NET Framework, there are interfaces for immutable [dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.iimmutabledictionary-2?view=net-7.0), [lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.iimmutablelist-1?view=net-7.0), [queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.iimmutablequeue-1?view=net-7.0), [sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.iimmutableset-1?view=net-7.0), [stacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.iimmutablestack-1?view=net-7.0).

But there is no interface for [immutable arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1?view=net-7.0) to be found.

Also, [immutable arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1?view=net-7.0) are implemented as a `struct` in contrast to others which are `class`.

Can you explain why such design?

Comment: Probably because they would be equivalent to `IReadOnlyList<T>` and/or `IImmutableList<T>`. ImmutableArray implements both of these.

Comment: What should be difference between `IImmutableList<T>`/`IReadOnlyList<T>` and `IImmutableArray<T>`?

Comment: Also note that this is not .NET Framework but .NET/.NET Core =)

Comment: [The remark section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1?view=net-7.0#remarks) shows `ImmutableArray` is the optimized version of `ImmutableList` under specific scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general interfaces and classes don't have an one-to-one relationship in .NET. For example see [a recent comment](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/80327#issuecomment-1377454266) by a Microsoft engineer on GitHib:

> We generally don't expose collection abstractions, unless the BCL contains a reasonable number of implementations that share the same feature set.

By *"collection abstractions"* they mean interfaces. Some immutable collections do have such a relationship, like the `ImmutableQueue<T>` collection and the `IImmutableQueue<T>` interface, but you could see them more as an exception than the rule.

The [`ImmutableArray<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1?view=net-7.0) struct is interesting. You can learn why it was implemented as a `struct` in [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/please-welcome-immutablearrayt/) by Immo Landwerth. Quote:

> `ImmutableArray<T>` is a very thin wrapper around a regular array and thus shares all the benefits with them. We even made it a value type (struct) as it only has a single field which holds the array it wraps. This makes the size of the value type identical to the reference of the array. In other words: passing around an immutable array is as cheap as passing around the underlying array. Since it’s a value type, there is also no additional object allocation necessary to create the immutable wrapper, which can reduce GC pressure.

The `ImmutableArray<T>` implements many interfaces, but if you store it as an interface in a variable or field, [it will be boxed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032750/structs-interfaces-and-boxing). So you generally don't want to do this. Preferably you'd want to store it and pass it around as is.

Answer (score 3):

`ImmutableArray<T>` and `ImmutableList<T>` are functionally compatible types, so implementing just `IImmutableList<T>` is enough for both.

They differ only in characteristics, which is described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1#remarks):

- `ImmutableArray<T>` uses an actual underlying array, so accessing an element by index is an O(1) operation, whereas adding a new element (and thus creating a new array and copying all items from the previous one) has an O(n) cost
- In contrast, `ImmutableList<T>` is represented as a binary tree, so both element access by index and adding a new item have O(log N) cost.

Additionally, `ImmutableArray<T>` is a `struct` so if used directly, accessing the underlying array is very fast. However, if it is boxed (eg. using as an interface implementation, including LINQ), its usage will be somewhat slower.

Conclusion: you must decide which one fits better for your needs. If you typically create it once and then just access elements `ImmutableArray<T>` (or even a simple `List<T>` can be better). But if you add new elements more frequently than access them by index, then `ImmutableList<T>` can be a more optimal choice.