# Type-safe discriminated unions in C#, or: How to limit the number of implementations of an interface?

Tags: c#, interface, f#, discriminated-union, algebraic-data-types

First, sorry for the lengthy post. Basically, my question is this:

I'm trying to reproduce the following F# discriminated union type in C#:

```ml
type Relation =
     | LessThan of obj * obj
     | EqualTo of obj * obj
     | GreaterThan of obj * obj
```

Can anyone suggest a simpler interface-based solution than the following?

---

```
interface IRelation // concrete types represent ◊ in the expression "Subject ◊ Object"
{
    object Subject { get; }
    object Object  { get; }
}

struct LessThanRelation    : IRelation { … }
struct EqualToRelation     : IRelation { … }
struct GreaterThanRelation : IRelation { … }
```

All my algorithms recognise these three relation types, and these only, so I need to prevent any further implementations of `IRelation` by third parties (i.e. other assemblies).

> *<sub>**Footnote:** To some, it might occur that if I just got my interface and algorithms right in terms of object orientation / polymorphism, it shouldn't matter that an third-party implementation is injected into my algorithm methods, as long as the interface is implemented correctly. This is a valid critique. But let's just assume that for the moment that I'm favouring a more functional-programming style over strict object-orientation in this case.</sub>*

My best idea so far is to declare all above types as `internal` (ie. they will never be seen directly by outsiders) and create a proxy type `Relation`, which will be the only visible type to third parties:

```
public struct Relation  // constructors etc. are omitted here for brevity's sake
{
    public RelationType Type { get { … /* concrete type of value -> enum value */ } }

    public Relation Subject  { get { return value.Subject; } }
    public Relation Object   { get { return value.Object;  } }

    internal readonly IRelation value;
}

public enum RelationType
{
    LessThan,
    EqualTo,
    GreaterThan
}
```

All is well so far, but it gets more elaborate…

- … if I expose factory methods for the concrete relation types:

  ```
  public Relation CreateLessThanRelation(…)
  {
      return new Relation { value = new LessThanRelation { … } };
  }
  ```
- … whenever I expose an algorithm working on relation types, because I must map from/to the proxy type:

  ```
  public … ExposedAlgorithm(this IEnumerable<Relation> relations)
  {
      // forward unwrapped IRelation objects to an internal algorithm method:
      return InternalAlgorithm(from relation in relations select relation.value);
  }
  ```

Comment: You know that if you use a struct through its interface, the struct is boxed, right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63671/is-it-safe-for-structs-to-implement-interfaces/63757#63757

Comment: **@delnan**, are you referring to "limiting the number of implementations of an interface" (then see the "footnote" in the middle of my answer), or to "doing discriminated unions in C#"? **@xanatos**, good point! I didn't think about that, as I'm not too concerned about performance right now... or would you suggest a simple change from `struct` to `class`, even though that doesn't make sense (as these types should have value semantics)?

Comment: @xanatos - there is an exception to that (isn't there always?), but this isn't it...

Comment: xanatos a generic type T with a generic interface constraint T : ISomeInterface; this is then **constrained** rather than boxed; meaning the appropriate call is made *without* needing to box. there is a special op-code just for this.

Comment: (it also applies to a non-generic method on a generic type, obviously)

Comment: Hi, I mae a library for doign DU's in c#. You have a base class which has an internal ctor, and you can seal the subtypes. https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Limiting the **interface** implementations means it isn't really acting as an interface (which should accept any implementation (substitution), such as decorators) - so I can't recommend that.

Also, note that with a small exception of generics, treating a struct as an interface leads to boxing.

So that leaves one interesting case; an abstract ***class*** with a ***private*** constructor, and a known number of implementations *as nested types*, which means that they have access to the private constructor.

Now you control the subtypes, boxing isn't an issue (as it is a class), and there is less expectation of substitution.

Comment: I would have loved my implementation types to be `struct`s (that's how I ended up with interfaces in the first place, since inheritance doesn't work with value types), but you do make a good case against it.

Comment: and using an internal constructor without nested classes (but in same Assembly)?

Comment: @xanatos - yes, non-nested and internal is about the same

Answer (score 6):

I think your general approach is going in the right direction, but it looks like you can simplify your code using abstract classes:

```
public abstract class Relation
{
    internal Relation(object subject, object obj)
    {
        Subject = subject;
        Object = obj;
    }
    public object Subject { get; private set; }
    public object Object { get; private set; }
}

public sealed class LessThanRelation : Relation
{
    public LessThanRelation(object subject, object obj) : base(subject, obj) { }
}

public sealed class EqualToRelation : Relation
{
    public EqualToRelation(object subject, object obj) : base(subject, obj) { }
}

public sealed class GreaterThanRelation : Relation
{
    public GreaterThanRelation(object subject, object obj) : base(subject, obj) { }
}
```

Outside assemblies can see all the members of the `Relation` class **except** the internal constructor -- which, from the outside, makes it appear that the class has no constructors defined, so its not possible for third-party assemblies to define their own implementations.

Comment: Thanks, Jon Skeet, for the blog post which inspired this answer :) http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/10/03/the-curious-case-of-the-publicity-seeking-interface-and-the-shy-abstract-class.aspx

Comment: Or, as xanatos suggests in a comment to another answer, you could just make the base class' constructor `internal` and drop the `GetNull` method...?

Comment: +1 @stakx: don't know why I didn't think of that :) Updated answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with the idea based on `enum`. In fact, I would use that solution in F# too. Since you always have only two arguments, you don't really need discriminated union:

```
// Note: with numbers assigned to cases, this becomes enum
type RelationType =      
  | LessThan = 1
  | EqualTo = 2
  | GreaterThan = 3

// Single-case union (could be record, depending on your style)
type Relation = 
  | BinaryRelation of RelationType * obj * obj
```

In general, if you want to encode discriminated union in C# then it is probably the best option to use *abstract base class* and then inherited class for each cases (with additional fields). Since you're not planing to extend it by adding new subclasses, you can define *tag enum* that lists all the possible subtypes (so that you can easily implement "pattern matching" by `switch` on the tag).

Comment: concerning your F# suggestion: I suppose the difference is only in the way one will match patterns, e.g.: `match relation with | LessThan (_, _) -> …` vs. `match relation with | (LessThan, _, _) -> …`. Are there any performance or memory benefits to the latter approach?