# Implications of using a class through an interface

Tags: c#, class, interface

*What are the implications of using a class through an interface as opposed to using the class directly?*

For example when mutating a list of integers through the `IList<Int32>` interface as opposed to using the `List<Int32>` class directly. Does this introduce boxing conversions, more type checks, null checks, more levels of indirection, virtual calls, reduced optimizations, prevent method inlining? If so, how can I mitigate some of that?

I am writing a library in which I intend all collection classes to be used through their interfaces. The library is for other developers who might want to use it in a high-performance setting.

Comment: If you are so much worried about performance why not use arrays rather then collection classes

Comment: So you'd rather not know and just blindly use arrays... That's one way. I am not _so much worried_ and just want to know the issues. Only then can one make a good assessment in a particular situation.

Comment: Coz the info is CLR implementation specific and it may change in future versions, that't the whole purpose of VMs - to abstract away details that you should not depend upon

Comment: @Ankur: I don't believe this is implementation-specific. The CLI standard (ECMA-335) goes to great lengths specifying virtual dispatch (`virtual`, `newslot`/`reuseslot`, `call`/`callvirt`, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Boxing

AFAIK, interfaces do not introduce any additional boxing if the implementing types are reference (i.e. `class`) types. If the implementing type itself is a value type (i.e. a `struct`), then that value type will be boxed when assigned to a variable of the interface type:

```
struct Foo : IFooBar { … }           class Bar : IFooBar { … }
IFooBar foo = new Foo();             IFooBar bar = new Bar();
//          ^                                    ^
//       boxing                              no boxing
```

This is because interface types are treated like reference types; remember that you *could* assign `null` to a `IFooBar`-typed variable, but not to a `Foo`-typed variable!

> <sub>**Side note:** If the implementing type is a `struct`, perhaps see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63671/is-it-safe-for-structs-to-implement-interfaces), too.</sub>

### Virtual dispatch

However, methods that implement an interface method are internally treated similarly to virtual methods; i.e. they get a slot in a dispatch table like a virtual method would, even if you have not declared the implementing method `virtual`.

Don't worry too much about this. Virtual method dispatch should not be seen as a problem in an object-oriented language — it's just normal. You're not likely to see any performance issues caused by it.