# interface as argument or generic method with where - what is the difference?

Tags: c#, generics

Is any difference between :

```
public void Method1<T>(class1 c, T obj) where T:Imyinterface
```

And

```
public void Method2(class1 c, Imyinterface obj)
```

?

What are the benefits of use the first one method?

Comment: I would say, in this case, they have the same functionality.

Comment: One difference is that structs will be boxed when calling the second version which will be avoided in the generic method.

Comment: @Lee see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63671/is-it-safe-for-structs-to-implement-interfaces). You should generally avoid inheriting interfaces in structs

Comment: @Amit - There's no reason why structs shouldn't implement interfaces - in fact they should usually implement `IEquatable<T>` to avoid boxing on equality comparisons. Generics like the above usage above avoid the very case that answer talks about!

Comment: @Lee - I agree, my comment was too hasty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While in your scenario it's practically the same (except for the fact that with method accepting interface parameter it will upcast concrete object to interface type) consider slightly different scenario. Let's say we want our method to accept only class that implements two interfaces `IMyInterface1` and `IMyInterface2` and that otherwise code should not compile :

```
interface IMyInterface1 { }    

interface IMyInterface2 { }

class MyClass : IMyInterface1 { }

public void Method1<T>(Class1 c, T obj) where T : IMyInterface1, IMyInterface2
{

}
```

If we create method that accepts interface as it's second parameter it will not satisfy the condition because it doesn't restrict user from sending class instance that implements only one interface but doesn't implements the second interface like it is for MyClass and IMyInterface2 in this example.

And what interface should user send ? He don't really know the type that needs to send on compile-time.

This is a good spot to use generic and generic constrains and on the other hand we cannot use single interface parameter.

Comment: this is the answer what I'm looking for

Answer (score 4):

Using a generic method gives you various possibilities with slight signature changes:

1. `public void Method1<T>(class1 c, T obj) where T:Imyinterface, new()`:
   This allows to instantiate new instances of type *T*.
2. `public T Method1<T>(class1 c, T obj) where T:Imyinterface`:
   This allows you to use the method without casting it's return value when needed.
3. `public void Method1<T>(class1 c, ref T obj) where T:Imyinterface`:
   This allows you to assing a new value to `obj`'s reference. Same applies to `out`.

These are impossible with the non generic version.

Comment: to instantiate instances of generic type, you have to add [new constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx) to constraint list. if not, it will not compile

Comment: @GianPaolo - good point, and I've expanded my answer a bit as well.

Answer (score 4):

As noted, with void methods, there is not much difference in usage.

If you look behind the scenes you will see that with the generic method, .NET will compile a separate method for each type you call it with.  This has the effect of avoiding boxing when called with a struct.

The big difference occurs when you use a return type.

`public T Method1<T>(class1 c, T obj) where T: IMyInterface`

and

`public IMyinterface Method2(class1 c, IMyInterface obj)`

With the generic version, you get the original type back, so you can continue calling properties or methods (instance or extension) on the original type.

With the non-generic version, you only get back a value of type `IMyInterface`, so you can only call properties or methods that are part of `IMyInterface`.

**This is most interesting, in my book, when used with extension methods and a fluent-style API.**

```
public static T Move<T>(this T animal) where T : ICanMove
{
    return animal;
}

public static T Fly<T>(this T animal) where T : ICanFly
{
    return animal;
}

public static T Pounce<T>(this T animal) where T : ICanPounce
{

    return animal;
}
```

Given that Tiger implements ICanMove and ICanPounce and the Eagle implements ICanMove and ICanFly, I can call the above extension methods that apply to the original type.  Intellisense will show .Fly() and .Move() available for an Eagle, and .Pounce() and a .Move() for a Tiger.

```
var birdie = new Eagle();

birdie
    .Move()
    .Fly()
    .Move()
    .Fly();

var kitty = new Tiger();

kitty
    .Move()
    .Pounce()
    .Move()
    .Pounce();
```

Here is what it would look like if you implemented Move non-generically:

```
public static ICanMove Move<T>(this ICanMove animal) 
{
    return animal;
}
```

Since an ICanMove interface is returned, the compiler has no idea that it was originally an Eagle or a Tiger, and so you can only use extensions, methods, or properties that are part of the ICanMove interface.

Answer (score 0):

There is no big difference for `void` methods.

```
public void Method1<T>(class1 c, T obj) where T : Imyinterface
```

equals to

```
public void Method2(class1 c, Imyinterface obj, Type t)
```

where `t` must be `Imyinterface`.

So if you need to pass some `Type` to your method, and you need to apply some constraints to that `Type` at compile-time, use the generic method.