# Constrain interface implementations to structs?

Tags: c#, inheritance, struct

An interface in C# can inherit another interface, e.g.

```
interface IFoo : IComparable { }
```

On the other hand, the following declaration is illegal:

```
interface IBar : struct { } // Invalid syntax
```

Is there any way an interface can be declared so that the implementing type is constrained to be a `struct`?

Comment: `interface IFoo<T> where T: struct{
 
}`

Comment: there is no support to resrict an interface to be implemented by only structs.

Comment: Correct, and so is this `interface IBar : class { } `. You do not restrict an interface but you can extend it. That is what `interface IFoo : IComparable` is, it states that `IFoo` extends the `IComparable` interface (*not that it is restricted to `IComparable`*)

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh That does not put the `struct` constraint on the implementing type.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh Nothing would hinder me from writing `class C : IFoo<int>`

Comment: It cannot be done like this, but maybe we can help with the workaround for an actual problem you are solving.

Comment: yes, but you can restrict the data type the class operates on.

Comment: there is  no such  constaint in c#  AFAK

Comment: This sounds a bit like an XY problem, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Implementing an interface in a struct normally is a **bad** idea... It nearly always causes boxing. No problem in doing it, it will work... But you shouldn't unless you know what you are doing... [Thread about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63671/is-it-safe-for-structs-to-implement-interfaces)

Comment: @xanatos but almost all built-in structs in .NET (like int and so on) implement a whole bunch of interfaces.

Comment: @DavidG Yes, it is an "XY" problem, but at this point I am content with getting a response to the above question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Evk i added a *But you shouldn't unless you know what you are doing*... I hope that Microsoft programmers are in the group of "know what you are doing" :-)

Comment: You can implement generic interface with T restricted to struct and create a property `T Self {get;}`. If that is implemented by class - it will have to at least provide you some struct to work with. If implemented by struct - it can return itself.

Comment: @Evk Interesting thought with the `Self` concept. One upvote for the idea :-)

Comment: The one responsible for the downvote, please feel free to comment why you consider this to be a downvotable question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way an interface can be declared so that the implementing type is constrained to be a struct?

No, that is currently not possible and neither is the inverse (ensuring an interface is implemented by a class).

---

As far as documentation goes the closest thing I was able to find was this [Interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx), [Interfaces (c#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx), [Inheritance - Interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx#Interfaces). I doubt there will be anything on an official MS site simply because (in most cases) there is no documentation on non-existing features (*ignoring feature requests or features in progress*) and this could be considered a non-existent feature.

Closest [excerpt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) I could find

> A class or struct can implement multiple interfaces. ...

Comment: Thanks. If you have a pointer e.g. to a paragraph in the C# Language Specification where this is stated, I'd be more than happy to accept this answer.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson - ok, this is the closest I could find.

Comment: Fair enough :-) Thanks for your efforts, Igor.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42999660/constrain-interface-implementations-to-structs/42999886?noredirect=1#comment73089400_42999660) splendid comment by user @Evk, I realized that it is *almost* possible to constrain the implementation of an interface to be a `struct` (or analogously, a `class`).

The interface could be implemented as a generic interface, where the generic type parameter is constrained to be a `struct` that implements the interface itself:

```
interface IBar<T> where T : struct, IBar<T> { }
```

Now I can declare a `struct` that implements `IBar`:

```
struct BarStruct : IBar<BarStruct> { } // Works fine.
```

But, I *cannot* declare a `class` that implements `IBar` in the same way, since the generic type parameter is restricted to be a `struct`:

```
class BarClass : IBar<BarClass> { } // Will not compile!
```

However, it is not a waterproof approach: as user @Igor points out in the comment below, the following will still compile:

```
class BarClass : IBar<BarStruct> { }
```

Comment: Although a step in the right direction it would not stop you from writing `class BarClass : IBar<BarStruct> { }` assuming that  `BarStruct` is defined.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Maybe I got carried away there for a moment :-) Maybe there is no solution after all...

Comment: Although not water tight maybe its good enough for what you need. I upvoted it anyway for creativity :)

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it is not entirely what I need, but it was an entertaining exercise nevertheless.

Comment: @Evk :-) I have worked around the issue, so right now it is not worthwhile to describe it in more detail. But who knows, maybe I'll post a follow-up question...

Answer (score 2):

You can not declare interface of struct, because classes and structs can only implement the interfaces. But you can declare interface with generic parameter as struct:

```
interface IBar<T> where T : struct
{
    void Foo(T val); // T always be struct
}
```

And implement this interface:

```
class Bar : IBar<int>
{
    public void Foo(int val) { }
}
```

Comment: That is not the same as what the OP is asking though. Essentially they want `Bar` to be forced to be a `struct` instead of a `class` via a restriction on `IBar`

Comment: Yes, I am fully aware of this possibility, but it is not what I need. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Probably better: *interface IBar<T> where T : struct, IBar<T>* , because the sentence is ***the implementing type** is constrained*