# Does any built-in value type in C# implement any interface?

Tags: c#, value-type, boxing

I'm studying Boxing in C#. And it says if a value type such as a struct implements an interface, there is a boxing operation when we assign an object of type struct to a variable of the type of the interface that has been implemented by the struct.

Now this is my question. Is there any built-in value type such as "int" or "double" that has implemented any interface?

Comment: Where did you get that statement from? IMHO, boxing and unboxing is not related to interfaces. It happens without interfaces.

Comment: Look at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32) for `int` - it implements a whole bunch of interfaces

Comment: The whole [generic math](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math) feature is based on interfaces, with generic methods used to avoid the boxing problem. In general, structs are usually used for memory/performance reasons, and then you usually want to avoid interfaces anyway, or only use them for generic constraints.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63671/is-it-safe-for-structs-to-implement-interfaces

Comment: They pretty much all do, which you could see for yourself by reading the relevant documentation. You should ALWAYS read the relevant documentation before posting a question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the standard numeric value types implement quite a few interfaces, namely `IEquatable`, `IComparable` and `IConvertible`. With .NET 7.0, many more where added in preparation for the support of generic math.

It is correct that if you do something like

```
int x = 2;
IEquatable<int> eq = x;
if (eq.Equals(3))
{
    // ...
}
```

a boxing conversion is necessary. However, if you write this like

```
int x = 2;
if (x.Equals(3)) 
// ...
```

the compiler will typically emit a direct call to the `Equals` method, avoiding the boxing. And of course, if you simply write `if (x == 3)` no boxing is involved too, because the compiler directly inserts the instruction for a numeric equality test.