# Why can't I set the margin of a FlowLayoutPanel programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, margin

I'm trying to set the margin of a FlowPanel programmatically in C#, however it tells me that I can't set it because it isn't a variable.

Here it is telling me that the property gets or sets the space between controls.

[image: Normal property?]

But, once I try to set the property, it tells me that it isn't a variable and the project won't compile.

[image: Am I crazy, or what?]

So, what is happening here? Is this property declared in a weird way behind the scenes? Is it a problem with Visual Studio? I'm at a loss.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the value of an element in a list of structs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51526/changing-the-value-of-an-element-in-a-list-of-structs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must assign a new value:

```
flowLayoutPanel2.margin = new Padding(5);
```

Update: Although there is no such remark for Padding there is an explaination for Point which also is a structure and why it need to be set as a new Padding (Point in the following description):

> Point **[Padding] is a structure, which means that it is a value type. If you
>   access a property in Point, a copy of the property is returned.
>   Therefore, changing the X or Y properties of the Point returned from
>   the Location property will not affect the Left, Right, Top, or Bottom
>   property values of the Form**. To adjust these properties, set each
>   property value individually, or set the Location property with a new
>   Point.

Source:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159414.aspx

```
Public Structure Padding
```

Padding:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.padding.aspx

Comment: I can see how that works, but I wanted to know what was unique about the property itself that prevented the assignment.

Comment: @elucid8 I updated my answer with a little more information on that.