# C# struct in a list

Tags: c#, struct

Quick question about structs...
I have a struct, lets pretend it looks like this:

```
struct myStruct {
     public int x, y;
}
```

And then I make a list filled with that struct

```
List<myStruct> myList = new List<myStruct>;
```

And then later I loop through the list and I want to change the value of x...

```
for(int i=0; i<myList.Count; i++) {

     ...//do stuff to x

     myList[i].x = newX;
}
```

> Cannot modify the return value of 'List<myform.myStruct>.this[int]'
>   because it is not a variable

Can you please clear up any confusion I'm having as to why it's not letting me change the value of x.

Comment: This is why you should never make mutable structs.

Comment: Question has already been asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51526/changing-the-value-of-an-element-in-a-list-of-structs

Comment: If you need to mutate the values in the list, why not use a `class` instead like `Tuple<int,int>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A struct is a value type, and is passed by value. When you say `myList[i].x = newX` you're assigning to the `x` property of a **copy** of the `i`th element of `myList`, which would be thrown away after the statement is executed. Luckily the compiler will stop you from making this mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Structs are value types. So the return of the indexer is a temporary copy of the value in the list which cannot be modified. You have to replace the struct in the list:

```
var val = myList[i];
val.x = newX;
myList[i] = val;
```

Comment: This is what I ultimately did, but I was curious as to why I was getting that error. Thanks.