# String Constructor not working in unity c#

Tags: unity-game-engine, struct, constructor

Salutations, this'll be brief.

So, I tried to change the name of one the hero struct in my game, but it doesn't update, neither in the inspector nor in the de facto code.

I can call the constructor just fine, and if I print the heroname before and after (in the constructor), it tells me the new name. However, It does not change.

Here is the (simplified) code:

```
//This already has a name in the inspector that I want to override
public List<TroopStat> PlayerHeroStats = new List<TroopStat>();    


void Start () {
    PlayerHeroStats[0].ChangeTroopType();
}

[System.Serializable]
public struct TroopStat {
    public string nameOfTroop;

    public void ChangeTroopType() {
        nameOfTroop = "Blabla";
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structs are value types. You need to assign a new struct or use class instead.

This should work:

```
void Start () {
    TroopStat stat = PlayerHeroStats[0]; 
    stat.ChangeTroopType();
    PlayerHeroStats[0] = stat;
}
```

Or make the `TroopStat` a class.

You can read more about it [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51526/changing-the-value-of-an-element-in-a-list-of-structs)

Comment: Thank you very much, kind sir. Works like a charm.
Decided against using that as a class for clarity reasons in the inspector :D