# Fastest way of incrementing an element of a List<(Guid, int)>

Tags: c#, list, performance, .net-7.0, valuetuple

I have a [`List<(Guid, int)>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) (a list of [value-tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples)), and I want to increment the [`Item2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-2.item2) field of an element at a specified index. Based on the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51526/changing-the-value-of-an-element-in-a-list-of-structs), there are two ways to do it:

1. The first is to get a copy of the existing `(Guid, int)` at the specified index, increment the `Item2` field of the copy, and replace the existing element with the copy.
2. The second is to use the [`CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.asspan) API (.NET 5), get the `Span<(Guid, int)>` representation of the backing array of the list, and update in-place the `Item2` of the desirable element.

```
static void Increment1(List<(Guid, int)> list, int index)
{
    (Guid, int) copy = list[index];
    copy.Item2++;
    list[index] = copy;
}

static void Increment2(List<(Guid, int)> list, int index)
{
    Span<(Guid, int)> span = CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan(list);
    span[index].Item2++;
}
```

Which of these two approaches is the most performant on the latest .NET platform (.NET 7)?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249841/discussion-on-question-by-theodor-zoulias-fastest-way-of-incrementing-an-element).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to treat this as a more general question about benchmarking so this answer is more generally useful. I'll use your proposed algorithms as an example though.

---

A naive approach to benchmarking in .NET would be to execute your algorithm wrapped in a `StopWatch`, however, except for the most crude of estimations, (talk order of magnitude levels of accuracy), this is pretty useless. So please don't do this. Use `BenchmarkDotNet` instead.

For simple tests such as this, it's very simple.

1. Create a console app.
2. Install the package through NuGet.
3. Create a test class
4. Create a method for each of your tests and annotate with `[Benchmark]`
5. Create a setup method to get your data ready and annotate it with either `[GlobalSetup]` or `[IterationSetup]` depending on whether or not you want it resetting between each test.
6. Add a single-line top-level statement to run your tests.

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Reports;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

Summary? summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<IncrementBenchmark>();


public class IncrementBenchmark
{
    private List<(Guid, int)> _testData = new();
    
    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _testData = new();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            _testData.Add((Guid.NewGuid(), Random.Shared.Next()));
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void IndexCopyBasedIncrement()
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < _testData.Count; i++)
        {
            (Guid, int) copy = _testData[i];
            copy.Item2++;
            _testData[i] = copy;
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void SpanBasedIncrement()
    {
        Span<(Guid, int)> span = CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan(_testData);
        for (int i = 0; i < _testData.Count; i++)
        {
            span[i].Item2++;
        }
    }
}
```

Then run your console app and wait for the results.

In this case, the span-based implementation is an order of magnitude faster.

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IndexCopyBasedIncrement | 70.743 us | 0.3260 us | 0.3049 us |
| SpanBasedIncrement | 4.679 us | 0.0419 us | 0.0391 us |

Given the massive improvements made in .NET 7 to LINQ, you might be able to get further improvements by replacing my loop with something that can make use of those improvements, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Interestingly my home-made benchmark shows that the advanced `Span`-based approach is only 4 times faster than the indexer-based approach. I get 6.7 nsec and 23.8 nsec duration per operation respectively. And [the same benchmark](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bhXW88) on the .NET Fiddle server gives the opposite results, with the `Span`-based approach being a bit slower! (16.2 nsec vs 14.3 nsec). The results are not changing when I switch between .NET 6 and .NET 7. I ran the benchmark on Release mode.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - What were you using for your homemade benchmark? Unless it was a specific benchmarking framework, there are a whole load of confounding factors that really make rolling your own benchmark pretty impossible to get right (I've been there)

Comment: I am using the code that I have posted [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bhXW88), which is based on a `Stopwatch`.

Comment: Aye, unfortunately Stopwatch causes all sorts of trouble when you're trying to benchmark... Wish it came with a warning to not use it for that

Comment: What happens if, in `SpanBasedIncrement()`, you replace `i < _testData.Count` with `i < span.Length`?