# Best way to update a value in a List variable being passed to a multi-threaded method

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, interlocked-increment

As if its not obvious from my question, first time trying to work with multi-threading and need some help. I have a method that is now being called by multiple threads concurrently and it is being passed a variable (defined as shown below). The part I am having problems with is the updating of the "counter" (`numProcessed`) part of the custom `List` var, which is supposed to keep track of the total number of rows processed across all threads. I assume, this should likely be a class instead of this overcomplicated List structure, but trying to work within the current confines.

```
DoWorkMethod(List<(String dataSetCode, int dataSetNum, int rowCount, double modVal,
    int numProcessed, List<Task> queryTasks)> lstDataSetCdTasks)
```

```
//CS1612 Error Workaround
var temp = lstDataSetCdTasks[dataSetNum];
//Interlocked.Exchange(
//    ref temp.numProcessed,lstDataSetCdTasks[dataSetNum].numProcessed + 1);
temp.numProcessed = lstDataSetCdTasks[dataSetNum].numProcessed + 1;
lstDataSetCdTasks[dataSetNum] = temp;

currRow.Cells["Extract"].Value = lstDataSetCdTasks[dataSetNum].numProcessed / 
lstDataSetCdTasks[dataSetNum].modVal + "| % (" + 
lstDataSetCdTasks.ElementAt(dataSetNum).queryTasks.Count + " threads)";
```

What is the best way to update this counter in a thread safe manner? I thought I needed to use `Interlocked.Exchange()` given I cant update `lstDataSetCdTasks` directly and I have to assign that first to some temp variable then back in order to work around the CS1612 error. However, it still seems to fail to update very sporadically.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Interlocked.Increment` maybe?

Comment: I cant update the lstDataSetCdTasks directly due to CS1612 Error so cant use Increment on it. Also, unless I am missing something, since its still "losing" or "missing" some of the increments using Exchange, I wouldnt think Increment would work either. I am thinking that maybe the issue is with assignment of temp back to my lstDataSetCdTasks structure, but not sure how to work around that in the best way (if thats even the issue). Thanks!

Comment: `Exchange` doesn't work because you are adding the value outside of that atomic instruction. `Increment` does it all in one go. You need a function on the class which owns that property which can increment it, you cannot `ref` a property. So therefore you can't do that either. Maybe just a normal `lock` statement?

Comment: Gotcha. I changed to using a class instead of that struct. So I now have a method that updates my "counter". However, I need to keep the "counter" in a List<int> because I have multiple "datasets" and each one has multiple threads. I am trying to keep this "counter" for each "dataset", but across threads within each "dataset". So trying to do something like the following is still trying to ref a property, right? Interlocked.Increment(ref numProcesseds[listPos]); where numProcessed is my list of integer counters for each dataset. Should I just use a lock in my method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `List<T>` class [is thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020486/listt-thread-safety) only for multiple readers. As long as you add a writer in the mix, you must synchronize all interactions with the collection, otherwise its behavior is undefined. The simplest synchronization tool is the [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) statement. This statement requires a locker `object`, which can be any reference type, and usually is either a dedicated `new object()` or the list itself. The locker [should not "leak"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/why-is-lockthis-bad) to the outside world, so using the list itself as the locker is only viable if the list is internal, and you don't expose it to unknown code.

For demonstration purposes I'll show an example with a simpler list than your `lstDataSetCdTasks`, a list that contains value tuples with just two members. I am showing three approaches of incrementing the `NumProcessed` member . Take a look at them, and I'll explain them below:

```
List<(string DataSetCode, int NumProcessed)> list
    = new() { ("A", 0), ("B", 0), ("C", 0) };
int index = 1;
Console.WriteLine($"Before: {String.Join(", ", list)}");

lock (list)
{
    (string DataSetCode, int NumProcessed) temp = list[index];
    temp.NumProcessed++;
    list[index] = temp;
}
Console.WriteLine($"After1: {String.Join(", ", list)}");

lock (list)
{
    Span<(string DataSetCode, int NumProcessed)> span = CollectionsMarshal
        .AsSpan(list);
    span[index].NumProcessed++;
}
Console.WriteLine($"After2: {String.Join(", ", list)}");

// Incorrect code, for educational purposes only
{
    Span<(string DataSetCode, int NumProcessed)> span = CollectionsMarshal
        .AsSpan(list);
    Interlocked.Increment(ref span[index].NumProcessed);
}
Console.WriteLine($"After3: {String.Join(", ", list)}");
```

Output:

```
Before: (A, 0), (B, 0), (C, 0)
After1: (A, 0), (B, 1), (C, 0)
After2: (A, 0), (B, 2), (C, 0)
After3: (A, 0), (B, 3), (C, 0)
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/flidKE).

The first approach locks on the `list`, creating a protected region that only one thread can enter at a time¹. Inside the protected region we store a copy of a tuple in a `temp` variable, we mutate the copy, and then we replace the existing tuple in the list with the mutated copy. This is the simplest way to mutate a value-type stored in a `List<T>`.

The second approach again locks on the `list`, and then uses the advanced [`CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.asspan) to get a `Span<T>` representation of the list. With the `Span<T>` you gain direct access to the backing array of the list, and so you can mutate the stored value-tuples in-place, without using temporary variables. This is [the most efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74546579/fastest-way-of-incrementing-an-element-of-a-listguid-int/74760771#74760771) way of mutating value-types stored in a `List<T>`.

The third approach doesn't use the `lock` statement, and instead attempts to grab the `Span<T>` and then mutate an entry with the [`Interlocked.Increment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment) method. This is valid C# code, but it is not thread-safe and it has undefined behavior. The problem is that another thread might perform concurrently an action that will replace the backing array of the list, in which case the mutation performed by the current thread will be lost. This would be a valid approach though if instead of a list you stored your tuples in an array (`(string DataSetCode, int NumProcessed)[]`). The arrays have fixed length, so they are less versatile than lists. But they open some opportunities for lock-free multithreading, opportunities that lists totally lack. I am not advising you to pursue these opportunities though. As a beginner in multithreading, it's much safer to stick with the `lock`. As long as you don't do anything heavy inside the protected regions, the `lock`s [are cheap](https://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Locking_Performance) and won't slow down your application.

¹ <sub>Provided that all other interactions with the list are performed in `lock` regions protected with the same locker. Caution: even a single unprotected interaction with the list, even reading the `Count` property, renders your program invalid and it's behavior undefined. Enumerating the list should also be enclosed in a protected region. Interacting with the [`List<T>.Enumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.enumerator) counts as interacting with the list itself.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use the concurrent.futures module as it provides a common interface for Multithreading and Multiprocessing in Python.
[concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor)

ProcessPoolExecutor  == CPU heavy tasks such as calculating pi
ThreadPoolExecutor   == i/o heavy, wait states such as web-scraping

Provided map function makes it super easy to pass an array in and out. It does however lack fine granularity and control over exceptions and timeouts.
Don't use 'map' if you need control over timeouts or exception handling.

[ThreadPoolExecutor in Python: The Complete Guide](https://superfastpython.com/threadpoolexecutor-in-python/) has a very good explanation for mostly everything on that subject.

Be warned: only use multi-x if you absolutely need it as it is:

- More overhead in processing
- More complex in programming
- Slower to troubleshoot
- Potentially slower in processing